# Detect when user returns from using EmailComposeTask?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I noticed the user is redirected back to our app after sending an email using the EmailComposeTask. Is there maybe a Completed event handler for this or someway to determine when the user returns back to our app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The NavigatedTo event will be raised when the control comes back to your page.

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Microsoft Silverlight

Comment: How would I determine if I am navigating to our page from the EmailComposeTask? Also is there a way to determine if the email was sent successfully?

Comment: You can set yourself a flag in your state when navigating to the EmailComposeTask. On the next NavigatedTo event you can then check whether you are returning from the EmailComposeTask or from somewhere else.

Comment: I'm assuming we could use the same method for the SMSComposeTask?

Comment: But how do I get that user press on cancel button or send button in mail composer ?

Answer (score -4):

Yes there is a completed event handler.

[Here](http://www.blog.ingenuitynow.net/WP7+Tip+Using+The+CameraCaptureTask+For+Windows+Phone+7.aspx) is how to do it for CameraCaptureTask. EmailComposeTask should be the same.

Comment: Unlike the CamerCaptureTask, the EmailComposeTask does not have a completed event.

Comment: Just discovered that. Choosers have completed event. Launchers do not. Wouldn't the app be tombstoned? If so can we use the Activated event?