# A way to determine if the email was sent successfully using EmailComposeTask

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am using `EmailComposeTask` in windows phone to use native email application.

Doubt is how can I determine whether the email has been sent successfully or not? As we don't have Completed event for `EmailComposeTask`.

I do this using c#.

Comment: There is no way to know it.

Comment: EmailComposeTask is a "Launcher", so there is no event to notify the result. Seems like your question is already answere here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614379/detect-when-user-returns-from-using-emailcomposetask

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way. Since EmailComposeTask does not expose a completed handler, there is no way of knowing if the user even sent the mail, let alone if the mail was sent successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to determine the email was sent successfully or not. Only way is just checking in the Inbox.